# In Eclipse, why doesn't "Show In" appear for non-Java files?

Tags: java, eclipse

If I have a *java file open, I can right click on the source, scroll down to "Show In (Alt-Shift-W)", and select Navigator.

If I have an *xml, *jsp, or pretty much anything besides a Java source file, that option doesn't appear.  Is there any way to get it to appear, or any similar functionality that will let me jump immediately to the correct folder in Navigator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'link with editor' button on the Navigator view.  It forces the Navigator view to change to whatever file the active editor has open. If you click a different editor or open a resource/type, it will update the Navigator at the same time.

On my version of Eclipse (3.4.2), it looks like two arrows, one above the other. The top one points left and the bottom one points right. The fly-over helptext on my Eclipse reads 'Link with editor'. The same button appears in the Project Explorer as well.  I'm pretty sure the button has been there since before version 3.

Comment: Where would I find the button?  What does it look like?  I don't see any likely suspects in my version of Eclipse (3.2.2) (Thank you!)

Comment: Updated answer with description of the button.

Comment: Did you ever know that you're my hero?  Did you ever know what you mean to me?  (In other words, thank you!)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Eclipse Platform Version: 3.4.2 (Build id: M20090211-1700) and works fine for all kind of files.

Comment: Websphere Integration Developer built on top of 3.2.2.  Might be time to find an update to WID.

Comment: If I don't remember wrong, I downloaded it as Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 3.4 and then updated with Oracle Enterprise Pack

Answer (score 0):

Is that "other" file a part of your project? Because it most certainly works for me on both XML and JSP (and many others).

Comment: Yes, part of the project; appears my version of Eclipse might be dated and the problem here.